# Web2py form process fails

Tags: python, web2py

I have created a custom form using SQLFORM.factory.

When this form is submitted, postback takes place and it comes to index method of my controller.

If I write below given line to validate the form, it evaluates to False.

```
if searchform.process().accepted:#THIS CONDITION EVALUATES TO FALSE
```

But if I replace this line with below given line, it evaluates to True.

```
if searchform.accepts(request):#THIS CONDITION EVALUATES TO TRUE
```

Below given condition fails as well.

```
if searchform.accepts(request,session):#THIS CONDITION EVALUATES TO FALSE
```

I am clueless about why this is happening. I believe the preferable condition shoul be the first one.

The code to create this form is given in more details below:

```
searchform=SQLFORM.factory(
    Field('id', 'unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('account','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('fromdate','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('todate','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('name','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('status','integer'),
    Field('method',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_SET(['Method1','Method2','Method3'], sort=True, zero='Select'))), 
    Field('type','unicode',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_SET(['Type1','Type2',], sort=True, zero='Select'))), 
    Field('altname','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    Field('group','unicode',requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_SET(['Group1','Group2',], sort=True, zero='Select'))), 
    Field('assignee','unicode',requires=empty_to_none),
    submit_button = 'Search'
)
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `session` to `.accepts()`, that will add a hidden `_formkey` field to the form (and add the same value to the session) in order to protect against CSRF attacks. Upon form submission, `.accepts()` will confirm that the submitted `_formkey` value matches the value stored in the session -- otherwise validation will fail. (Note, the `.process()` method is just a shortcut for `.accepts(request, session)`).

Because validation is failing only when you exclude the `session` from `.accepts()`, it appears that (a) in the view, the hidden `_formkey` field is not getting included in the form when it is serialized to HTML, (b) the session cookie is not getting sent back to the server with the form post, and/or (c) the `_formkey` value is somehow getting cleared from the session (e.g., via something like `session.clear()`).

The most likely culprit is (a). If you have created custom form HTML in the view, you must include the hidden `_formname` and `_formkey` fields. The easiest way is via:

```
{{=form.custom.end}}  # includes the closing </form> tag
```

or:

```
{{=form.hidden_fields()}}  # does not include the closing </form> tag
```

The individual hidden field values are in `form.formname` and `form.formkey`.

Comment: This is an old post but it seems to fit my problem. I created a custom form and ended it with {{=form.custom.end}}. Submit fails at the first try (no formkey in the html) but later works. If in the controller I have return(form=form.process()) it works, but I can't get it to have it work with keepvalues=True. Any clues?