# Web2py Form fails to process at first try

Tags: python, forms, web2py

I created a SQLFORM that creates a new entry and also a FORM to delete that entry. But when I try to use that FORM (fill it and hit the submit) but at the  first try it always returns false.

```
form.process().accepted:
```

My controllers :

```
def new_category():
    form = SQLFORM(db.category)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'category create form accepted'
    return dict(form=form)

def delete_category():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_name='name', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),\
                INPUT(_type='submit'))
    if db(db.category.name==request.vars.name).select():
        if form.process().accepted:
            response.flash = 'category delete form accepted'
            db(db.category.name==request.vars.name).delete()
        else:
            response.flash = 'category delete form refused'
    else:
        response.flash = 'category delete form refused (no category)'
    return dict(form=form)
```

My Models :

```
db.define_table('category',Field('name'))
```

My create / delete views :

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>This is the test/delete_category.html template</h2>
{{=form}}

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>This is the test/new_category.html template</h2>
{{=form}}
```

After the first try (when i fill the form and submit it) it works as it should. I look at similiar question at [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733169/web2py-form-process-fails) but using `accepts(request)` doesn't work either.

Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

your model looks peculiar, for you haven't set what is the data type of Field name.
it should be ....Field('name','string')